Why does Android Developer document illustrate that Activity's onDestroy is called before ViewModel's onCleared?
I used debugging points to figure out the order of ViewModel's onCleared and Activity's onDestroy().
Because ComponentActivity class had below code, I knew ViewModel's onCleared() called and then Activity's onDestroy() callback.
getLifecycle().addObserver(new LifecycleEventObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull LifecycleOwner source,
                    @NonNull Lifecycle.Event event) {
                if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) {
                    // Clear out the available context
                    mContextAwareHelper.clearAvailableContext();
                    // And clear the ViewModelStore
                    if (!isChangingConfigurations()) {
                        getViewModelStore().clear(); <- check
                    }
                    mReportFullyDrawnExecutor.activityDestroyed();
                }
            }
        });

I don't understand ViewModel diagram illustration figure 1 in Android Developer document. link
I think change the order of Activity's onDestroy() and ViewModel's onCleared() like figure 2.
Why is the illustration explained like figure 1?

First thing to understand is that destroying an Android activity is not the same as destroying an object instance.
The activity instance still exists, it is now in a state where nothing more useful can be done with it.
This observer is called when onDestroy is called, so the figure is correct in that Activity.onDestroy() is invoked before ViewModel.onCleared()
It might be more correct to show that ViewModel.onCleared() is invoked within the context of Activity.onDestroy()
The point that the figure is trying to make is:  If you have a lifecycle-aware view model observer, onDestroy() will cause it to properly exit before the view model is cleared.
mReportFullyDrawnExecutor is a helper that notifies other parts of the app that the activity drawing operation is complete, and apparently it needs to be notified that the activity it's concerned with has been destroyed.  This is just a notification; it's safe to say the majority of the work of onDestroy() has already happened at this point.
